# Persist data: Angular 4

Tags: angular, api

I'm working  with a real world project in Angular 4. I've an API and database which gets me an Array of Recipes. Now I also have a Recipe details page(Details about a single recipe) and when I click a recipe from the list of recipe, I navigate to single recipe page and also emits that(clicked) recipe using Subject. On single Recipe page I display the details.

But I want to persist the data(single recipe) on single recipe page even if I reload that single page. Do I need to do this using an API call on this page or is there any method to achieve without making an API call?

Comment: Show code... it is really hard to understand by reading a description only.

Comment: One way is you can use `localStorage` for this and get it from there.How ever the best way will be to use service worker.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist in your database, you will have to make a request to the API layer. See PUT and POST requests [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/core-http-api/) and use whichever is suitable based in the API layer you use.

In case you only want to store it in the browser. (It will not be visible for other users, or other browsers) you can use [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

You'll have to explain the problem better to get a more detailed answer.